# Why can i see black screen when using BlocBuilder though i have taken all possible measures?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, flutter-bloc

This is my main file, I am trying to check for internet connection.And showing dialog if there is no internet connection using flutter cubit.

But the only hurdle is for a flicker of second the screen goes black and then dialog is displayed , how can i avoid this?

`main.file`

```
void main() {
  runApp(BlocProvider(
    create: (BuildContext context) => ConnectivityCubit()..checkConnectivity(),
    lazy: false,
    child: MaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  bool _isDialogDisplayed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ConnectivityCubit, ConnectivityState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state == ConnectivityState.disconnected) {
          _isDialogDisplayed = true;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
              title: Text('No Internet'),
              content: Text('Please check your internet connection.'),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state == ConnectivityState.connected &&
            _isDialogDisplayed == true) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          _isDialogDisplayed = false;
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state == ConnectivityState.init) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return MaterialApp(     //   <-- This is causing problem
          home: Scaffold(                         
            body: state == ConnectivityState.connected
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text('Hello World'),
                  )
                : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`cubit.file`

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

enum ConnectivityState { connected, disconnected, init }

class ConnectivityCubit extends Cubit<ConnectivityState> {
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult>? _subscription;
  late Stream<ConnectivityResult> streamValue;
  ConnectivityCubit() : super(ConnectivityState.init) {
    streamValue = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged;
    _subscription = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        emit(ConnectivityState.disconnected);
      } else {
        emit(ConnectivityState.connected);
      }
    });
  }

  checkConnectivity() async {
    final result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      emit(ConnectivityState.disconnected);
    } else {
      emit(ConnectivityState.connected);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

I have tried to simply use this way

```
return const MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          )),
        );
```

The above code solves black screen issue but it will show `Hello World` for fraction of second i.e because of the time taken to build dialog by the `BlocListener`. To overcome that I tried the above method. Though i have things wrapped inside the `MaterialApp` why do i see black screen?

Answer (score 0):

you want builder part in check status and then showDialog()

```
  MyApp({super.key});
  bool _isDialogDisplayed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
  body:  BlocConsumer<ConnectivityCubit, ConnectivityState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state == ConnectivityState.disconnected) {
          _isDialogDisplayed = true;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
              title: Text('No Internet'),
              content: Text('Please check your internet connection.'),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state == ConnectivityState.connected &&
            _isDialogDisplayed == true) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          _isDialogDisplayed = false;
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state == ConnectivityState.init) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
     else if(state == ConnectivityState.disconnected){
          _isDialogDisplayed = true;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
              title: Text('No Internet'),
              content: Text('Please check your internet connection.'),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
     );
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work !!!